# Why is my python script still running in the backgroud on EC2 even after I quit putty?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ps

According to this [question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232564/how-to-continuously-run-a-python-script-on-an-ec2-server), the script I run should be terminated with my terminal session, unless i use `nohup` or `screen`. However when I

```
sudo python b.py &
```

with `b.py` being:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import datetime
import time
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',level=logging.WARNING,format='%(message)s')
logging.warning('start')

while True:
    s = (datetime.datetime.now().minute) *60 + datetime.datetime.now().second
    if ((s)%(60*5) <= 6) : #True: #
        logging.error((strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))) 
    time.sleep(5)
```

then

```
exit
```

and log in using putty again, the `test.log` is still being updated, and when i do

```
ps -Alf | grep python,
```

the processes show up:

```
4 S root     11179     1  0  80   0 - 16974 poll_s 15:44 ?        00:00:00 sudo python b.py
4 S root     11180 11179  0  80   0 - 10652 poll_s 15:44 ?        00:00:00 python b.py
```

although `jobs` command doesn't return anything.

why is it so? according to other's experience `b.py` should have stopped when i logged out of the terminal. I'm using the Ubuntu AMI on a micro instance.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems more relevant for http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

The & puts it in the background, so it will continue to run until it's pid is killed, and since you ran it with sudo you will need to kill the pid with sudo as well.

kill -9 11179